# multiple domains mysql

Tags: mysql

I am configuring mysql for my server, but I have one question: Is it possible for each domain to see their own mysql server, but only having to run one service at the server? I want to keep al databases for the domains separated, but I don't want to have to prefix each database name.

edit:
sorry I think my question wasn't clear enough:
I know I can create several users with different permissions, but what I want is that different domain can create different databases with the same name.
eg: suppose I have domain1.com and a domain2.com running on the same server. Both domains want a database called statistics.
If I want to do this now, I'll have to prefix the databases, so there are two databases: domain1_statistics and domain2_statistics, and the domains can only access their own databases. But I want to create 2 databases called statistics, one for each domain, so that each domain only sees its own statistics database. Is this possible?

edit2:
how can I transfer this post to serverfault? Sorry for posting on the wrong site!

Comment: not programming related, belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single MySQL server then that server doesn't care whether a domain X or domain Y can see "their" databases, because MySQL determines who can do what based on the user who connected to the server. If you want to restrict access, create multiple MySQL user accounts and configure each of your domains to use one of those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple usernames to use in each domain that can only access their own database, you only need one MySQL instance running that way and each user can only see tables they are privileged too.